# MS-Word - Pulling down cell content to the next page if a table is broken by a page-break

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table in Word that has column titles. When the page breaks the table rolls over to the next page and the headers repeat. However, I also have section titles that are important to see as well. If you look at the example below, I have the section '2' at the top next to sub-section 'C'.

a) I will be generating MHTML dynamically for import into Word so if it is possible to generate MHTML that will enable the above then that would be great. Otherwise ...

b) Is there any way within Word to manually or using VBA mark up the sections so they know to roll over to the next page automatically, so that the table will update itself if there are any changes to page-break locations. Alternatively...

c) I might have to write some VBA that checks that the section numbers are in the right place every time the VBA code is manually run, although I suspect that might start to get messy as I will also have to remove any existing 'pulled' section numbers that might have been inserted.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What about inserting the section number in every row? Then the problem just goes away.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what the client wants. I suppose I could insert it and then change the font to white if it isn't the first in the series or the first on the page ...

Comment: Sometime you have to tell the client what is technically possible and what is not. Now's your chance.

Comment: I was getting close to that anyway but just wanted to make sure that there wasn't an existing way of doing it. I'm sure if possible they'd also want it to print, fold, pop in an envelope and post itself.